# How to parse data vertically in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have data printed out in the console like this:

```
A B C D E
1 2 3 4 5
```

I want to manipulate it so `A:1 B:2 C:3 D:4 E:5` is printed.

What is the best way to go about it? Should I tokenize the two lines and then print it out using arrays?

How do I go about it in bash?

Comment: Are there always 2 lines with 5 words each, or do you need this to scale?

Comment: There are always constant number of lines with constant number of words each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk is good for this.

```
awk 'NR==1{for(i=0;i<NF;i++){row[i]=$i}} NR==2{for(i=0;i<NF;i++){printf "%s:%s",row[i],$i}}' oldfile > newfile
```

A slightly more readable version for scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

NR == 1 {
    for(i = 0; i < NF; i++) {
        first_row[i] = $i
    }
}
NR == 2 {
    for(i = 0; i < NF; i++) {
        printf "%s:%s", first_row[i], $i
    }
    print ""
}
```

If you want it to scale vertically, you'll have to say how.

Comment: I would assume the way to scale vertically is with additional pairs, in which case you would just need to replace the `NR == 1` and `NR == 2` with `NR % 2 == 1` and `NR % 2 == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

For two lines with any number of elements:

```
(read LINE;
 LINE_ONE=($LINE);
 read LINE;
 LINE_TWO=($LINE);
 for i in `seq 0 $((${#LINE_ONE[@]} - 1))`;
 do
     echo ${LINE_ONE[$i]}:${LINE_TWO[$i]};
 done)
```

To do pairs of lines just wrap it in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e "A B C D E FFF GGG\n1 2 3 4 5 666 7" |
sed 's/ \|$/:/g;N;:a;s/\([^:]*:\)\([^\n]*\)\n\([^: ]\+ *\)/\2\1\3\n/;ta;s/\n//'
A:1 B:2 C:3 D:4 E:5 FFF:666 GGG:7
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lane 'if($.%2){@k=@F}else{print join" ",map{"$k[$_]:$F[$_]"}0..$#F}'
```

Somewhat more legible version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
my @keys;
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  if ($. % 2) {  # odd lines are keys
     @keys = split ' ', $_;
  } else { # even lines are values
     my @values = split ' ', $_;
     print join ' ', map { "$keys[$_]:$values[$_]" } 0..$#values;
  }
}
```